# Customize Body of SMTP Mail Script

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer, html-email

I have a basic smtp mail script that works great but the only thing that i need is to customize body of mail. I tried to define and insert values into the script but somewhere the code gives me error. Where I'm doing wrong?

```php
<?
require("class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();                                   // send via SMTP
$mail->Host     = "mail.host.com"; // SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "info@host.com";  // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "123456"; // SMTP password

$mail->From     = "info@host.com"; 
$mail->Fromname = "John Doe";
$mail->AddAddress("info@gmail.com","John Doe");
$mail->Subject  =  $_POST['content'];
$mail->Body     = (".$arrival_date.", ".$arrival_pickup_location.", ".$arrival_dropoff_location.", ".$arrival_flight_number.", ".$arrival_fligth_time.", ".$arrival_dropoff_adress.", ".$phone_number.", ".$reservation_name.", ".$email_adress.", ".$country.", ".$additional_requests.");

$arrival_date = $_POST['arrival_date'];
$arrival_pickup_location = $_POST['arrival_pickup_location'];
$arrival_dropoff_location = $_POST['arrival_dropoff_location'];
$arrival_flight_number = $_POST['arrival_flight_number'];
$arrival_fligth_time = $_POST['arrival_fligth_time'];
$arrival_dropoff_adress = $_POST['arrival_dropoff_adress'];
$reservation_name = $_POST['reservation_name'];
$phone_number = $_POST['phone_number'];
$email_adress = $_POST['email_adress'];
$passenger = $_POST['passenger'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$additional_requests = $_POST['additional_requests'];

if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo "Mesagge not delivered <p>";
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo "Message sent";


?>
```

Comment: You are using a very old and buggy version of PHPMailer. [Get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). Also, base your code on the examples provided with PHPMailer, not random obsolete ones you've found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the variables after you're trying to set the `$mail->Body` object with them.

Try:

```
<?php
$arrival_date = $_POST['arrival_date'];
$arrival_pickup_location = $_POST['arrival_pickup_location'];
$arrival_dropoff_location = $_POST['arrival_dropoff_location'];
$arrival_flight_number = $_POST['arrival_flight_number'];
$arrival_fligth_time = $_POST['arrival_fligth_time'];
$arrival_dropoff_adress = $_POST['arrival_dropoff_adress'];
$reservation_name = $_POST['reservation_name'];
$phone_number = $_POST['phone_number'];
$email_adress = $_POST['email_adress'];
$passenger = $_POST['passenger'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$additional_requests = $_POST['additional_requests'];

$message = '<ul><li>' . $arrival_date . "</li>";
$message .= '<li>' . $arrival_pickup_location . "</li>";
$message .= '<li>' . $arrival_dropoff_location . "</li>";
$message .= '<li>' . $arrival_flight_number . "</li>";
$message .= '<li>' . $arrival_fligth_time . "</li>";
$message .= '<li>' . $arrival_dropoff_adress . "</li>";
$message .= '<li>' . $phone_number . "</li>";
$message .= '<li>' . $reservation_name . "</li>";
$message .= '<li>' . $email_adress . "</li>";
$message .= '<li>' . $country . "</li>";
$message .= '<li>' . $additional_requests . "</li></ul>";

require("class.phpmailer.php");    
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); // send via SMTP
$mail->Host = "mail.host.com"; // SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "info@host.com";  // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "123456"; // SMTP password
$mail->IsHTML(true);   
$mail->From = "info@host.com"; 
$mail->Fromname = "John Doe";
$mail->AddAddress("info@gmail.com","John Doe");
$mail->Subject = $_POST['content'];
$mail->Body = $message;   

if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo "Mesagge not delivered <p>";
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}
echo "Message sent";
?>
```

Also, I don't think that using `$mail->AddAddress = ("info@gmail.com","John Doe");` would work, not sure ...

[image]

.. perhaps it does though! The way above in my answer definitely should work though xD!

Comment: Still got the error:( But now the error message said there is a problem with "$mail->Body     = (".$arrival_date.",..." line.

Comment: Patiently waiting.

Comment: Done, I've created a message variable by concatenating the required variables together, before there seemed to be a miss placed `"` but I think this way make it clearly to see what is happening.

Comment: this is wrong $mail->AddAddress("info@gmail.com","John Doe"); 
it needs to be $mail->AddAddress = ("info@gmail.com","John Doe");

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/sending-emails-php-phpmailer/ :

AddAddress is $mail->addAddress("recepient1@example.com", "Recepient Name");  Whereas $mail->From = "from@yourdomain.com"; etc.  One is a single value whereas the others are taking in an array.

Comment: It is working but still sending the body same as i did, ı would like to display the values under each other (name, surname etc)

Comment: I think i need a html body to make values positioned under each other?

Comment: Check edits :) will print them out on separate lines now.

Comment: Nope:( <li> displays as a text inside message now, something missing.

Comment: Ahh it also needs `$mail->IsHTML(true);` I have edited it accordingly!

Comment: No problem! Got there in the end! =D

Comment: You are using a very old and buggy version of PHPMailer. [Get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Answer (score -1):

What's the error that you're getting? Where did it start producing the error? 
$mail->AddAddress("info@gmail.com","John Doe") doesn't have an "=" sign.

so it should read:

```
 $mail->AddAddress = ("info@gmail.com","John Doe");
```

also, you can add html to the body so it reads a little nicer:

```
    $mail->Body    = "<html><body>";
    $mail->Body   .= "<table><tbody>";
    $mail->Body   .= "<tr><td>".$arrival_date."</td></tr>";
    $mail->Body   .= "</tbody></table>";
    $mail->Body   .= "</body></html>";
```

Comment: This is just wrong. `addAddress` is a method, not a property.